# Índice n inválido para esse OracleParameterCollection com Count=n

Tags: c#, nhibernate, oracle11g

Estou quebrando a cabeça para descobrir o motivo do erro.
Mapeamento da minha tabela:

```html
<class name="AtaReuniao" table="EPN.ATA_REUNIAO" lazy="true" where=" ARUN_IN_EXCLUIDO = 'N' ">
    <id name="Id" column="ARUN_SQ_REUNIAO" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">EPN.SQ_ARUN_SQ_REUNIAO</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="DataReuniao"                    column="ARUN_DT_REUNIAO"                type="DateTime" />
    <property name="Assunto"                        column="ARUN_TX_ASSUNTO"                type="string" length="100" />
    <property name="AtaFinalArquivo"                column="ARUN_MM_ATA_FINAL"              type="BinaryBlob" lazy="true"/>
    <property name="Observacao"                     column="ARUN_TX_OBSERVACAO"             type="string" length="1000" />
    <property name="IndicadorExcluido"              column="ARUN_IN_EXCLUIDO"               type="Infra.Util.EnumCharType`1[[Infra.Util.SimNao,Infra]], Infra" length="1"  />
    

    <set name="ParticipantesInterno" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="none" table="EPN.ATA_REUNIAO_PRTCPE_INTERNO">
      <key column="ARUN_SQ_REUNIAO"/>
      <many-to-many class="Usuario" column = "USER_ID" />
    </set>

    <set name="ParticipantesExterno" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
      <key column="ARUN_SQ_REUNIAO"/>
      <one-to-many class="AtaReuniaoParticipanteExterno" not-found="ignore"/>
    </set>

    <set name="AtaReuniaoBlocos" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true">
      <key column="ARUN_SQ_REUNIAO"/>
      <one-to-many class="AtaReuniaoBloco" not-found="ignore"/>
    </set>

    <set name="GruposEmpresariais" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="none" table="EPN.ATA_REUNIAO_GRUPO_EMPRESARIAL">
      <key column="ARUN_SQ_REUNIAO"/>
      <many-to-many class="GrupoEmpresarial" column="GREP_CD_SEQUENCIAL" />
    </set>

  </class>
```

Quando tento salvar um registro em ATA_REUNIAO ocorre o problema.
Como a mensagem do erro cita índice 3, especificamente, achei que o problema estivesse no AtaFinalArquivo que é um blob. Mas ao remover uns campos do mapeamento antes desse blob a mensagem de erro continuou indicando o índice 3.
Daí removi o campo DataReuniao que é obrigatório e a mensagem de erro parou, mas não faz sentido, pois o campo de date está mapeado da mesma forma que outros mapeamentos no sistema.

Já pesquisei em alguns sites mas não achei nada específico sobre OracleParameterCollection relacionado a campo Date.

Esse é o insert gerado pelo NHibernate:

> INSERT INTO EPN.ATA_REUNIAO (ARUN_DT_REUNIAO, ARUN_TX_ASSUNTO, ARUN_MM_ATA_FINAL, ARUN_TX_OBSERVACAO, arun_in_excluido, ARUN_NM_ANEXO_ATA_FINAL, ARUN_SQ_REUNIAO) VALUES (TO_DATE('07/10/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), 'teste assunto',  NULL , 'asd', 'N', NULL,  7 )

Essa é a classe utilizada no mapeamento:

```
public class AtaReuniao : EntityBase<Int32>
{

    public virtual DateTime? DataReuniao { get; set; }
    public virtual string Assunto { get; set; }
    public virtual string Observacao { get; set; }
    public virtual SimNao IndicadorExcluido { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] AtaFinalArquivo { get; set; }
    public virtual string NomeArquivo { get; set; }
    public virtual int TamanhoArquivo { get; set; }
    public virtual bool TemArquivo { get { return TamanhoArquivo > 0; } }
    public virtual ICollection<Usuario> ParticipantesInterno { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AtaReuniaoParticipanteExterno> ParticipantesExterno { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AtaReuniaoBloco> AtaReuniaoBlocos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AtaReuniaoBloco> AtaReuniaoBlocosOrdenado
    {
        get
        {
            return AtaReuniaoBlocos.OrderBy(a => a.Bloco.NomeBlocoOrdenado).ToList();
        }
    }
    public virtual ICollection<GrupoEmpresarial> GruposEmpresariais { get; set; }
}
```

Tabela:
[image: Tabela ATA_REUNIAO]

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver aqui, irei compartilhar caso alguém passe por esse problema.

Eu já tinha pesquisado antes e os problemas semelhantes diziam que a causa do erro era por causa de mapeamento de alguma propriedade duplicada. Mas eu havia verificado todos os mapeamentos de Ata_Reuniao e dos childs e não encontrei repetição.

Encontrei uma referência aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553437/invalid-index-13-for-this-sqlparametercollection-with-count-13 onde informa que campos Nullable do tipo Date e Int na tabela devem ter seu mapeamento no C# nullable também. Esse foi o problema, eu estava colocando `public virtual DateTime? DataReuniao { get; set; }` com "?" mas na tabela o campo é obrigatório. Por isso que quando eu removia o mapeamento de DataReuniao do xml o erro não ocorria.